# Selenium: How to open a html test using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I just recently started using Selenium. I intend to record the steps in my browser using the IDE and have it saved as default format html. I would like to know if it is possible when using C#, to import/open the test cases independently. Trying to distribute the test cases across a few different machines, and testing multiple interdependent test cases.

Comment: Have you considered hand-writing the tests in C# using WebDriver?

Comment: Probably, but not recommended. Record & playback is a false economy.

Comment: @Arran - I'm not sure what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @RichardEv, apologies, it was not directed to you, more the OP. Your idea of "hand writing" the tests is the best way to do this, it always has been and always will be.

Comment: test automation is a programming task and should be approached as such.  you should not have an entire suite based on Selenium IDE.  Only use the IDE for short things you need to accomplish where you don't need a full framework.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However considering the steps to be included in the test cases it could be very time consuming for product/page. I had test suite using HP QTP and it can go beyond 1k steps, and the tester is not too programming savvy. 
If programmatic way is better solution, I guess I would need to redesign a different approach, which I am not enlightened to yet. 
If possible, would like to explore the possibilities of reusing the IDE-generated test cases.

Comment: @sircapsalot Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: @Arran Would still like to see if able to reuse the IDE generated code.

Comment: Reviving an old thread - my apologies - however, this is a valid question, be it in a specific scenario:

We've got many people on our team who are not developers (Project Managers, Service Desk personnel), who would be happy to record system tests straight from the Selenium IDE.

I'd love to see a way for them to record, and save the HTML form of these tests into a shared location, where I can have some C# code consume the HTML test case, and execute the test, as a part of our scheduled CI processes...